# AJUDA JAVASCRIPT PASSOAPASSO

Tags: javascript

Eu comecei a pouco tempo a mexer com js, e estou com duvida em um código do qual estou aprendendo e não sei porque estou errando, quem puder me ajudar fico grato.

```js
function passoAPasso(){
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    console.log(i);
  }
}

passoAPasso();
```

[image: v]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** o problema afinal era porque estava chamando a função `passoApasso()`, era necessário apenas escrevar a função, o próprio programa chamava a função, por isso aparecia repetido os números.
O **código abaixo** serve apenas se quisesesse imprimir `01234`, sem o `\n`, vou deixar ele abaixo, mas **não é a resposta para a pergunta!**

---

**RESPOSTA ANTIGA**

O problema é que você está imprimindo com o `console.log` normalmente, então ela faz a quebra de linha:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Ao invés de imprimir `01234` como o exercicio pede, para resolver isso basta concatenar os números com uma string:

```js
function passoAPasso(){
  let concat = "";
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    concat = concat + (i + ""); // os números são convertido para string, porque você está somando ele com uma string, antes de concatenar
  }
  
  console.log(concat);
}

passoAPasso();
```

**Explicando um pouco o código:** na primeira iteração você tem `1 + ""`, o que gera `"1"`, ou seja, agora é uma string e entrão você faz `concat + "1"`, concat é uma string vazia, então o resultado é `"1"`.
Na segunda iteração, você tem `2 + ""`, o que gera `"2"`, e depois faz `concat + "2"`, o que gera `"12"` e assim por diante.

Comment: eu usei seu código e deu a seguinte resposta " Sua solução não passou as provas
Resultados do teste:
 Imprimir passoAPasso() deveria imprimir 01234 Ver detalhes
'01234\n01234\n' == '0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n'"

Comment: Faz um teste, use seu código inicial, mas não chame a função `passoApasso()`, escreva somenta `function, pelo que parece está imprimindo duas vezes.

Comment: MUITOOOO OBRIGADOOOOOO CARAAA TAVA MÓ TEMPÃO TENTANDO RESOLVER E QUE SOU MEIO BURRINHO NO JS AINDA. VALEUU MSM.

Comment: Acontece haha, segue firme!